# Differentiate two integrals with variable limits

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Let's say $$v= \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\int_{c(t)}^{d(t)} F(s,\tau)dsd\tau$$
How would I compute $\frac{dv}{dt}$. I'm very lost on how to do this. So if anyone has a clue on what theorems to use, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: How does this rule apply to a double integral?

Comment: There is also a formula for the differentiation w.r.t. $t$ for the function $t\to G(u(t),v(t))$ (with involved functions of a corresponding class $\mathcal C^1$)... (General chain rule...)